# Moisture sensor for Mixers

Tags: control-engineering, sensors, concrete

I'm looking for alternatives to measure the moisture content in a concrete mixer machine. The ones on the market are expensive, like Hidro-Mix for apparent reasons; mixers are a hostile environment for sensors.

Any information on alternative methods to measure and visualise the humidity inside a mixer or have an economical sensor brand for this purpose is welcome.